# Google Assistant custom action/intent similar to Siri Kit for a mobile application

Tags: android

I see the actions console where you can build out a google action (which is pretty similar to Alexa). but, I was hoping there would be something similar to the way Apple handles this.

1. Say a phrase into Google Assistant, "AppName Shortcut"
2. Google Assistant would respond with a question. "Name?"
3. I answer
4. Google Assistant would ask another question. "Phone Number?"
5. I answer
6. Google Assistant would another another question. "Address?"
7. I answer

The assistant makes an API call into my endpoint, and their response is what my server responds with. I have not found anything that handles google assistant like that.

Comment: It's quite possible that google's.... uh Google(as in the assistant) is based server side rather than client side both literally and figuratively, as in technically its server side, and in assess to the client's device its not able to edit the server's software

Comment: Are you asking a [Action for Google (cloud service)](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational) question or a [Google App Action for Android](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents) question?

Comment: @MorrisonChang I was working with Actions Console... which seems to be for Google Home stuff. The Google App Action is what I was looking for, but I didnt see anything where I can have a conversation and grab the variables. Unless I didn't dig in the right place.

Comment: Google App Action handles the limited set of intents which while can be [complicated](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/finance/create-money-transfer#example-queries) is not conversational/interactive. If you need interactivity, you'll have to use the Action for Google cloud based service, or build it into the Android app yourself.

Comment: Thanks @MorrisonChang . Is there any good documentation on it? Like how to pull the value from the slots when you call my webhook. Or how to validation the slot input

Comment: Which "it" are you referring to? If Google Action (cloud) there is a codelab for that: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes, google action. I dont see how to get the action slot names. For example, if a user says a response to name, how do I get that response in the webhook so i can send it to an api? i dont  see any documentation for that, or sending an api request

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: [How to handle user names in Dialogflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55320213/295004). You should be looking at [Dialogflow](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs) documentation, although Google has recently released  Dialogflow CX for "complex interactions", I would start with [Dialogflow ES documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs) which is the standard one.